# Alignment issue when automating in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment, automation

I want to align a photo to a key object in Illustrator with automation. When using automation it does not align properly. I tried several times but failed. How do I align an object to a key object using automation?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Can you please [edit](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/130063/edit) your question and explain the steps you tried, and perhaps post a screenshot showing the problem. Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to show some of the automation code. In particular, the code that's causing the problem you're trying to solve. Then, someone here might be able to show where the code is going south and maybe even help you solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the object has empty sub objects at different positions, try removing them before you align. [image: empty sub objects]

[image: GRUPOS VACÍOS]